# Add a class to the closest parent class only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent

I want to add a class via jQuery to a parent div element with a shared class. I can use .closest to add the class added to the correct div.class but it also adds the class to the rest of the divs with the same target class.

So I only want the class adding to the child button.

```js
$('.trigger').on('click', function() {
  $('.myclass').addClass('current');
});
```

```css
.current {
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">
  <div style="background-color:red;">
    <div style="padding:10px">
      <button class="trigger">
        Button
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="myclass">
  <div style="background-color:blue;">
    <div style="padding:10px">
      <button class="trigger">
        Button
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/parents/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to selecting parent element has `.myclass`.

```js
$(".trigger").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest(".myclass").addClass("current");
});
```

```css
.current { margin: 30px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">
  <div style="background-color:red;">
    <div style="padding:10px">
      <button class="trigger">Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="myclass">
  <div style="background-color:blue;">
    <div style="padding:10px">
      <button class="trigger">Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Click away or on another button can we now remove the class we added?

Comment: @TomRudge Yes, you can use `.removeClass("className")` to remove class.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use $(this).closest('.myclass') method for closest parent class.

```
$('.trigger').on('click', function(){
     $(this).closest('.myclass').addClass('current');
});
```

Comment: The class needs to be added to the same div where "myclass" resides

Comment: So what is diffrence between my code and your code?

Comment: Nothing.. OP has not asked question properly before I have answered, after his comment i have modified my answer...!!